# How can I Insert each row With getdate() + 20 second

Tags: sql-server

How can I Insert row With getdate() + 20 second
Insert each row + 20 seconds

Example

```
insert into Student (id, Name, Mar,cTime)  
       select  id , Name , Mar , getdate() from sende
```

Expected Output  row + 20 seconds

```
| id| Name| Mar |   cTime             |
---------------------------------------
| 1 | ha1 | 100 | 2018-05-07 22:49:00 |
| 2 | ha2 | 200 | 2018-05-07 22:49:20 |
| 3 | ha3 | 300 | 2018-05-07 22:49:40 |
| 4 | ha4 | 400 | 2018-05-07 22:50:00 |
| 5 | ha5 | 500 | 2018-05-07 22:50:20 |
```

Comment: what is `2018-05-07 22:49:60`. Is it not actually `2018-05-07 22:50:00` which is your next row ?

Comment: You change the question to a very different one. At least include what is on sende

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir
If the first row is 2018-05-07 22:49:60
Next Row + 20 Seconds 2018-05-07 22:50:20
I appologise to you

Comment: `2018-05-07 22:49:60` isn't a real time stamp... minutes and seconds go from 0-59 unless i'm missing something

Comment: you are right Mr scsimon
I am mistaken I appologise to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to Sean answer, but instead of update just calculate the date before insert.

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/QLX58991)**

```
CREATE TABLE sende
    ([id] int, [Name] varchar(3), [Mar] int)
;

INSERT INTO sende
    ([id], [Name], [Mar])
VALUES
    (1, 'ha1', 100),
    (2, 'ha2', 200),
    (3, 'ha3', 300),
    (4, 'ha4', 400),
    (5, 'ha5', 500)
;

With cte as (
    SELECT *, row_number() over ( ORDER BY [id]) -1 as rn
    FROM sende
)    
SELECT *, DATEADD(ss, rn * 20, GETDATE()) as cTime
FROM cte
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the dateadd function:

```
declare @Student table  
(  
   id int ,  
   Name varchar(50),  
   Mar int ,
   cTime datetime 
)  

insert into @Student (id, Name, Mar,cTime)  
values(1,'ha1',100,getdate()),  
(2,'ha2',200, dateadd(s,20,getdate())),
(3,'ha3',300,dateadd(s,40,getdate())),  
(4,'ha4',400,dateadd(s,60,getdate())),
(5,'ha5',500,dateadd(s,80,getdate()))

select * from @Student
```

Comment: This is being way too literal with the example in the question.

Comment: I added the code necessary to solve the users question through the use of dateadd. It works without using multiple wait statements.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the manual way:

[**SQL DEMO**](http://rextester.com/AKZPXV91542)

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME
SET @date = GETDATE()

declare @Student table  
(  
   id int ,  
   Name varchar(50),  
   Mar int ,
   cTime datetime 
)  

insert into @Student (id, Name, Mar,cTime) values(1,'ha1',100, @date)
SET @date = DATEADD(ss, 20, @date)
insert into @Student (id, Name, Mar,cTime) values(2,'ha2',200, @date)
SET @date = DATEADD(ss, 20, @date)
insert into @Student (id, Name, Mar,cTime) values(3,'ha3',300, @date)
SET @date = DATEADD(ss, 20, @date)
insert into @Student (id, Name, Mar,cTime) values(4,'ha4',400, @date)
SET @date = DATEADD(ss, 20, @date)
insert into @Student (id, Name, Mar,cTime) values(5,'ha5',500, @date)
SET @date = DATEADD(ss, 20, @date)

SELECT * FROM @student
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this. Possibly using a tally table or some other logic during the insert. But here is another way. Just insert the data and then use ROW_NUMBER to update it. It will be dynamic in the number of rows and requires no hardcoding of values other than the original insert statement.

```
declare @Student table  
(  
   id int ,  
   Name varchar(50),  
   Mar int ,
   cTime datetime 
)  

;
insert into @Student (id, Name, Mar,cTime)  
    values(1, 'ha1', 100, getdate()),  
    (2, 'ha2', 200, getdate()),  
    (3, 'ha3', 300, getdate()),  
    (4, 'ha4', 400, getdate()),
    (5, 'ha5', 500, getdate())  

select * from @Student; --so you can see the original values

with MyCTE as
(
    select *
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id) - 1
    from @Student
)

update @Student
set cTime = dateadd(second, 20 * RowNum, c.cTime)
from MyCTE c;

select * from @Student; --every row is now 20 seconds greater than the row "before it"
```

Comment: another fun approach. i was trying to find a default value method, as i suspect the OP is over simplifying their question

Comment: @scsimon me too. This is a rather strange requirement that is either some professor with a horribly contrived question that makes no sense relative to anything in the real world or this is so over simplified it lost the point of the original issue.

Comment: Agreed, especially since they keep posting timestamps with seconds of `60` in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really make sense to insert data this way, and you aren't going to be inserting it that way from an application. Also, you are wanting 20 seconds sequentially for each row. When you do this for thousands of rows, it'd get messy. So, why not handle it on the `SELECT`?

```
declare @Student table  
(  
   id int ,  
   Name varchar(50),  
   Mar int ,
   cTime datetime 
)  

insert into @Student (id, Name, Mar)  
values
(1,'ha1',100),  
(2,'ha2',200),  
(3,'ha3',300),  
(4,'ha4',400),
(5,'ha5',500) 


select
    id
    ,name
    ,Mar
    ,cTime = dateadd(second,id * 20,getdate())
from @Student
```

Or, update the table after you have inserted everything, if there are going to be more than the sample 5 rows.

```
update @Student set cTime = dateadd(second,id * 20,getdate())


select * from @Student
```